# Cocoa, NSProxy, How to take over a method in an object?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsproxy

I need to replace a method in an object with my own implementation. For example,

```
Person *p; // some object
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject: p];
```

How can I replace addObject with a method of my own?

In other words, is there a way to replace the implementation of `addObject:` of a SPECIFIC object with another implementation?

I have been playing around with `NSProxy` but couldnt find out what I should do.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make that object an instance of a different class with a different implementation for the method.

Comment: It is partially correct, however, what happens to other objects having a reference to this object? Doesnt it create dangling references?
This change should be transparent to other objects.

Comment: Your class should be a subclass of `NSMutableArray`. It's transparent to other objects, which will can treat your `CustomizedArray` like any other mutable array. addObject will just behave a little differently, according to your implementation.

Comment: @noa: Subclassing NSMutableArray is not that simple. You'll have to reimplement the class's entire functionality if you do that.

Comment: @noa: NSMutableArray is part of the NSArray class cluster. It exists primarily as an interface. All NSArrays and NSMutableArrays that you use are actually instances of a private NSMutableArray subclass. If you subclass NSMutableArray, you don't get any of the actual functionality because it's all in NSCFArray.

Comment: Got it. Sounds like you need to reimplement it, then, or proxy it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a category to override the `:addObject` method of `NSMutableArray`. See the [Learn Objective-C tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) (section 11) for more information.

Comment: Overriding methods in categories is really not recommended, plus this would replace the method for *all* instances of `NSMutableArray`, not just the single instance as desired.

Comment: What if I need to take over the whole object while being able to undo this replacement at any time in future?
Furthermore, I need this change to be completely transparent to other objects having a reference to this object.
As jbrennan pointed out, I need to do it for some specific objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method swizzling approach for replacing methods runtime. There was actually a question as yours on SO, I think the finsl solution should work for you also - [Method swizzling for NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218750/method-swizzling-for-nsarray)