# Is there any way to monkey-patch or swizzle an NSArray (or other Class Cluster)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, monkeypatching, swizzling

Today I was working on a project in which I wanted to "alias" an alternative method for all instances of `NSArray`, and didn't think it would be too difficult with some [good old-fashioned method swizzling.](http://www.google.com/search?q=method%20Swizzling)

I broke out [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle.git) and…

`[NSArray jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(objectAtIndex:) withMethod:@selector(objectAtIndex_accordingToMe:) error:nil];`

To be clear, I paired this with the appropriate category on `NSArray`, an instance method called `objectAtIndex_accordingToMe:`.

However, I was just getting that *same old object, at that same old index*.  Sigh. Ultimately, I figured out that despite not throwing any errors - I'm not going to achieve these results [due to the fact that `NSArray` is a class cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7218794/547214)

I guess my question is more of an unwillingness to accept that "this" is really the end of the road trying to override `NSArray` methods.  I mean, come on this is `NSArray`.. people must wanna muck around with it, no?  One *would think* that Apple's foundation classes would be a prime target for swizzlers, everywhere!

So, is there a way to alter, alias, [monkey-patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), override, or otherwise have your way with… an NSArray, etc. (without subclassing)?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just a thought, but I've used the objective C runtime to swizzle in code before. At that lower level you can grab the class of a returned array and swizzle it directly rather than trying to use a category. Then the actual implementation class should not matter.

Comment: @NSResponder I often use a method `objectAtNormalizedIndex`, which acts like a sort of circular queue on NSArray - and I wanted to implement it here, but without a million changes to the existing code.  I never bothered with swizzling before, so I thought I'd see if I could make it happen, but I guess maybe there's a reason Apple seems to hate all things swizzle-related (SIMBL, etc).

Comment: Swizzling basic system classes will cause issues. Frameworks rely in a certain functionality, swizzling NSArray will break these assumptions and lead to extremely hard to reproduce bugs. Even if you could do this, please don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you have a particular array for which you'd like this behavior. You can get that instance's class object, no matter what it is, and swizzle that quite easily:

```
[[myArray class] jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(objectAtIndex:) withMethod:@selector(objectAtIndex_accordingToMe:) error:nil];
```

There's also only a few concrete subclasses of `NSArray`:

```
NSArray * trees = [NSArray array];
NSArray * birds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Albatross", @"Budgerigar", @"Cardinal", nil];
NSMutableArray * dogs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Airedale", @"Beagle", @"Collie", nil];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", [trees class], [birds class], [dogs class]);
```

We get `__NSArrayI` for the first two and `__NSArrayM` for the third, so *potentially* (this is *very* fragile) you could use a runtime function to grab the class object by name:

```
[objc_getClass("__NSArrayI") jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(objectAtIndex:) withMethod:@selector(objectAtIndex_accordingToMe:) error:nil];
```

Comment: could you just do `[objc_getClass(NSStringFromClass([myArray class])) jr_swizzleMethod…`?

Comment: No, because `objc_getClass()` takes a C string, not an `NSString`; it's unnecessary anyways, because `[myArray class]` will give you the same result.

Comment: How about  `[objc_getClass([NSStringFromClass([myArray class])) UTF8String] …`, lol.  Not being pedantic.. I just try not to be cavalier / moronic about introducing points of fragility. Oh wait, I forgot these aren't getting triggered when called.. but are pre-"registered".  Nevermind.. I see why that wouldn't work..

Comment: Yes, that works, but again, you don't need to do the converting to string and back to a class object. You already have the class object: `[myArray class] == objc_getClass([NSStringFromClass([myArray class])) UTFString])`, so just use the first option. The only reason I included the second is in case you (or a future reader) wanted to try swizzling _all_ the concrete subclasses they could find.

Comment: OK.. but once `[trees class]` has reported itself to be `__NSArrayI`, is that guaranteed for it's lifetime.. Or might the backend implementation change, without notice?  And I guess I had been imagining this would be able to work with all / any instances within a scope (amplifying such type-uncertainty, considerably).

Comment: It is possible in principle to change an object's class; admittedly occurrences of this are incredibly rare (I seem to recall that `NSMutableString` does an `NSPlaceholderString`/"real" class swap, but I may be wrong).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that a class can lie about the type of its instances by overriding `-[NSObject class]`, and the classes created by KVO at runtime do override `-[NSObject class]` to hide their existence. But `object_getClass` (different from `objc_getClass`!) always tells the truth.

Answer (score 4):

It's not just that it's a class cluster. `NSArray` is toll-free bridged to `CFArray`, and you can't swizzle Core Foundation. So this is very unlikely to work in general.

But what are you trying to solve? If you want to add a new method, use a category. They work on class clusters just fine. Modifying the behavior of some built-in on NSArray seems a recipe for disaster (entertaining as it might be as an exercise).

Before going *too* far, you probably want to at least take a look at [CFArray.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/CFArray.c) and understand how some of the underlying stuff is implemented.

---

EDIT: While I would never do this in production code, you may get some of what you want by hijacking individual array instances with ISA-swizzling. See [ISASwizzle](https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/tree/master/ch20/ISASwizzle) for some example code. The code explanation is in Chapter 20 of [iOS:PTL](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118818342.html). Search out for "isa swizzle" and you should find more on the net. It's how KVO is implemented. But with NSArray... wow, that's gotta be fragile.