# Method Swizzling isEqualToString

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm running into some odd behavior when trying to Method Swizzle `isEqualToString:` on the `NSString` class.  Here is the code in question:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>

@interface NSString (SwizzleString)
- (BOOL) custom_isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSRange)custom_rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString;
@end

@implementation NSString (SwizzleString)

- (BOOL) custom_isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString;
{
    NSLog(@"Inside custom_isEqualToString method definition");
    return [self custom_isEqualToString:aString];
}

- (NSRange)custom_rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString;
{
    NSLog(@"Inside custom_rangeOfString method definition");
    return [self custom_rangeOfString:aString];
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Method m1, m2;

    m1 = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(isEqualToString:));
    m2 = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(custom_isEqualToString:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2);

    m1 = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(rangeOfString:));
    m2 = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(custom_rangeOfString:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2);

    NSString *foo = @"Foo";

    // Does not log anything, is still using isEqualToString: implementation
    [foo isEqualToString:@"Foo"];
    // Also does not log anything, since it is using the method implementation from isEqualToString:
    [foo custom_isEqualToString:@"Foo"];

    // Does log something because rangeOfString now uses custom_rangeOfString IMP
    [foo rangeOfString:@"Foo"];
    // Does not log anything because it uses the method implementation from rangeOfString:
    [foo custom_rangeOfString:@"Foo"];
}
```

`isEqualToString:` and `rangeOfString:` are both defined in a category on `NSString` called `(NSStringExtensionMethods)`, so I included the `rangeOfString` swizzle to show that I'm swizzling methods correctly and specifically an `NSString` object successfully so I could eliminate questions about [class cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218750/method-swizzling-for-nsarray) problems.

When I produce the assembly for the code above, instead of seeing normal `objc_msgSend` calls I instead see stuff like `l_objc_msgSend_fixup_isEqualToString_`.  This led me to finding out more about the [objective-c vtable](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2011/06/17/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_vtable.html), in which it seems `isEqualToString:` can be found:

```
static const char * const defaultVtable[] = {
    "allocWithZone:", 
    "alloc", 
    "class", 
    "self", 
    "isKindOfClass:", 
    "respondsToSelector:", 
    "isFlipped", 
    "length", 
    "objectForKey:", 
    "count", 
    "objectAtIndex:", 
    "isEqualToString:", 
    "isEqual:", 
    "retain", 
    "release", 
    "autorelease", 
};
```

I've been digging through the objective-c source and the internet all day on how it would be possible to somehow still be able to swizzle `isEqualToString:`.

Comment: Don't **ever** swizzle things that implement the FlyWeight pattern and/or are a Class Cluster.  It's just a waste of time.

Comment: Wasting time isn't always a waste of time.  At this point I'm mainly just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're aware, this is a class cluster. You need the *actual* class, not the public class, so just ask the string object that you have:

```
NSString *foo = @"Foo";

m1 = class_getInstanceMethod([foo class], @selector(isEqualToString:));
m2 = class_getInstanceMethod([foo class], @selector(custom_isEqualToString:));
method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2);
```

There's also the fragile alternative of using the class name itself:

```
NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFConstantString")
NSClassFromString(@"__NSCFString")
```

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I tried that!  I do know about class clusters and have been swizzling methods on them with success but for some reason I must have overlooked this.  Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction!